# Rename pdb file with visual studio available tools?

Tags: visual-c++, pdb-files

A third party software that we build but typically do **not** modify in any way has some odd behaviour: Since it is build as a static lib, the PDB file it creates is called vc.pdb and is located in the softwares' intermediate folder. Now it creates about 12 of those pdb files, all in different folders, all with the same name for different libraries and different configurations.

When we integrate this third party software in our code we get the `LNK4099` warning because the baked in path for the pdb is obviously not there on all machines. Due to the fact that the third party software generates multiple .lib files in one output directory we cannot place the vc<...>.pdb file along with them.

So I am looking for a way to patch the lib files baked in pdb name to something I have under my control. Does Visual Studio build tools provide a way to do that?

*Edit:* Let me explain in greater detail what we are doing:
We decided to integrate some third party static lib in our projects. The project itself comes as a source package. One developer or the build server or whoever builds this source package which produces statically linked libs called a.lib and b.lib in various build configurations. With them the default visual studio configuration produces vc110.pdb files, because they are called all the same VS automatically put them into $(IntDir). So the pdb files are all over the place.
Now we commit these third party binaries to our VCS for the given project X.
Whoever now uses the static libs in project X has to link them into the final binary. This is the time where the LNK4099 is generated because the pdb files are not in the VCS and not available on this machine.

But we actually cannot commit all the vc110.pdb files, because this is useless. Since the full qualified path is build into the static libs, no other user will be able to replicate that. During linking the full path to the PDBs cannot be found so it looks for vc110.pdb in the location of the lib file.
Since the third party package decided to put a.lib and b.lib in the same directory we can never properly place the pdb files along with them unless we modify the build of the third party package and either rename the pdb files in the vcxproj or split the generation of libs to be in different directories (also in the vcxproj).

That's the point: I would like to *not* modify the build files of the third party at any time, I would like to be able to use a plain fresh download of this third party package and build it with some "simple" batch script.
The default results of this package are:

```
/Bin
    /Debug
        a.lib
        b.lib
    /Release
        a.lib
        b.lib
/Temp
    /A
        /Debug
            vc110.pdb
        /Release
            vc110.pdb
    /B
        /Debug
            vc110.pdb
        /Release
            vc110.pdb
```

What I really want is to patch the generated files *after* the build.
My "simple" batch (or whatever) script could for instance rename the pdb files to a.pdb and b.pdb, which of course would not be enough because the linker would still look for vc110.pdb as it is the compiled-in name. That is why I am looking for a way (via tools like lib or dumpbin, etc.)  where I can patch my generated libs to the new pdb name.

Like that:

```
$ magic /showPDB a.lib
> D:\some_users_machine\unique_path\package\Temp\A\Debug.vc110.pdb

$ magic /newPDB a.lib d:\path\a.pdb
> New PDB name is d:\path\a.pdb
```

When the consumer then links my patched a.lib it would not try to look for a.pdb at the path above. It would of course also not be found on most machines but then linker would also look for a a.pdb in the location where a.lib is located and that's were I could place it now for all.

*Edit 2:*  For the close due to opinion base: I am looking for a technical way to modify a static lib's baked in pdb location

Comment: Well, rather important that it works this way.  The *final* pdb file needs to match the executable file (dll or exe).  But that has to be postponed when you use a static library project, that pedal does not meet the metal until the library is linked.  At that point, debug entries in the vcxyz.pdb file are merged to produce the final one.  You are obviously doing something wrong when that generates linker warnings, you left no clue whatsoever what that might be.  First focus on getting this right for *one* configuration, the rest can wait.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the original post to clarify what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the linker option /PDBALTPATH.  This allows you to specify a different PDB path that will be embedded into your binary.

```
/PDBALTPATH:pdb_file_name
```

[MSDN Article: /PDBALTPATH (Use Alternate PDB Path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbaltpath-use-alternate-pdb-path)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem however is located in a situation after build. I did not build the static libs, so I cannot set any /PDBALTPATH on them as they are not maintained by me and I am looking for a way to modify their pdb path baked into them afterwards.

Comment: /PDBALTPATH actually is set at link time on your binary. But it probably won't do what you want, which is change the name of the PDB for the static lib. You could extract the lib with LIB /EXTRACT and then edit the paths manually, but I'm not sure if that would work as I haven't done it.